# qt configure issue with cross compilation: device and xplatform

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qt5, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile the latest Qt (version 5.9) for the raspberry pi compute module. I am quite new to this but found this guide very helpful: https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/

I followed the instruction but when it comes to configuring qt, I have the following command as suggested in the guide (I have replaced version 5.5 with 5.9):

`../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.0/configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5`

In my case this throws the error that I cannot specify both the `xplatform` and `device` parameters. I am new to this and I am not sure which one of the two should be specified!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select *mkspec* for configure you can select a host platform with `-platform`, or when cross-compiling you can select target platform with `-xplatform`. When cross-compiling for a specific *supported* device you select the mkspec with `-device`. You can give options for the specific device with `-device-option` flag. When using `-device` flag you don't use `-xplatform` flag.

In Qt, there seems to be a device mkspec for Raspberry Pi 2. You can find Qt mkspecs from qtbase module in Qt source tree, e.g. Raspberry Pi 2 mkspec: `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.0/qtbase/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi2-g++`.

There is [Raspberry Pi Beginners Guide](http://wiki.qt.io/Raspberry_Pi_Beginners_Guide) in Qt wiki which might be helpful. It says you should initially build qtbase and then compile other modules one by one. In the wiki there is an example configure command for Raspberry Pi 2 (in Linux host env) which uses `-device` and `-device-option` flags:

```
./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi
make -j 4
sudo make install
```